# D3 pie chart is not displaying for me

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Hi I am trying to Display D3 pie chart but i am getting only legend symbols ...can someone please help me to display d3 pie chart for dynamic data display.it will not show any errors only legend symbols displayed pie chart is not displaying.

here is the html i am using

```
    <script src="angularjs-nvd3-directives-master/examples/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angularjs-nvd3-directives-master/examples/js/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="angularjs-nvd3-directives-master/examples/js/nv.d3.js"></script>
    <script src="angularjs-nvd3-directives-master/dist/angularjs-nvd3-directives.js"></script>

    <link href="angularjs-nvd3-directives-master/examples/stylesheets/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
    #chart svg {
       height: 295px;
       width:300px;
    }
</style>
    <div id="chart">
       <svg></svg>
    </div>   

   and the javascript code i am using is...I want to display pie chart for dynamic data.


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Assets.asmx/Statereport",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess

    });
    function OnSuccess(data, status) {

        var myObject = JSON.parse(data.d);
        var source = {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
               { name: 'totsch' },
                { name: 'districtname' },
                { name: 'statename' }

            ],
            localdata: myObject
        };
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        var ObjectIDs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
            ObjectIDs.push(myObject[i].statename);
        }
        var gridquerystr = ObjectIDs[0].toString();


    nv.addGraph(function () {
        var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
            .x(function (d) { return d.label })
            .y(function (d) { return d.value })
            .showLabels(false);

        d3.select("#chart svg")
            .datum(myObject)
          .transition().duration(1200)
            .call(chart);

        return chart;
    });

please help me as soon as posssible..... or suggest me any opensource charts for displaying dynamic data using ajax json data . I am new to coding so please help 
[![d3 pie chart][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppqZf.jpg
```

Comment: Where is `myObject` defined? Besides, in your HTML code the CSS part is misplaced: It should be enclosed in `<style>` tags.

Comment: i put it into style tag only